# The remote name could not be resolved "www.google.com"

Tags: c#, dns, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am in a company network. In this network **i can't ping external** websites by IP. I can only call them by url like the browser does. Thats why i use **WebRequest**.

When i try to call "www.google.com" i got a "remote name could not be resolved (www.google.com)".

I have no "blocked" entry in my firewall. With this code i can call internal websites but not external.

This is my Code:

```
public void pingIP()
    {
        try
        {

            var url = uriBuilder;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.Uri);
            //request.Accept = "*/*";
            //request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            //request.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            //request.UserAgent = "Foo";
            //request.Accept = "*/*";
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            _PingByURL = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
        catch
        {

        }

    }
```

In app.config:

```
  <system.net>
      <defaultProxy enabled ="true" useDefaultCredentials = "true">
         <proxy usesystemdefault ="True" bypassonlocal="True"/>
      </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

How can i resolve the remote name? And is this the fast and cleanest way to check if a website is reachable by URL?

Thank you!

Comment: I know i have network restrictions that i can't ping google. But i want to call it by WebResponse to see if the website is availible.

Comment: Flush your dns from command line and see if that helps: ipconfig /flushdns. You can also run a tracert to see where it hops and blocks...10 to one at the dns.

Comment: i flushed the dns. The dns catch is empty. I tried again but it dont work.

Comment: With this code i got a WebResponse from the internal servers and if i logged of and use external Internet i can ping the external server because it dont use the proxy.pac

Answer (score 1):

This is working without a problem !

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(PingTest());
}

public static bool PingTest()
{
    Ping ping = new Ping();

    PingReply pingStatus = ping.Send(IPAddress.Parse("208.69.34.231"));
    //For the web address you need !
    //PingReply pingStatus = ping.Send("www.google.com");

    return pingStatus.Status == IPStatus.Success;

}
```

It is possible to have network restrictions and you are failing because of them.

Comment: I agree this works, but if you want to use this answer and are working with a url remove `IPAddress.Parse` and change the ip for a url

Comment: @SimonPrice Here I added it with url, you can see it !

Comment: pingStatus.Status got a timeout. I think it is because outgoing pings are blocked.

Comment: still with the new line i got "HostNotFound"

Comment: No. i cant ping external IPs. I can only call them by http request.

Comment: IF you can't ping google from the console don't expect to do it from the C# program, you have network restriction. Both lines work perfectly on my local system. So did you try to ping www.google.com in cmd ?

Comment: Yes i tryed and it faild. And i know i have network restriction about ping. But i want to call it with webresponse to see if the website is responding. This should work even with network restriction right?

Comment: Open the cmd and see if it working. You should write "ping www.google.com". If this failed, it will fail in the code too.

Comment: Yes. I know it will fail. Thats why i want to check it with WebResponse. _pingByIP is only for some Internal Servers!

Answer (score 0):

[image]this is what i use to ping which works for me

```
public bool ConnectedToInternet()
    {
        var myPing = new Ping();
        const string host = "google.com";
        var buffer = new byte[32];
        const int timeout = 1000;
        var pingOptions = new PingOptions();
        var reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
        return reply != null && reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;

    }
```

try this and let me know if you get a reply or not

Comment: Error on: var reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions); "Host not found"; I try exacly your code.

Comment: @Shadow ive just edited my answer to show you that this is working

Comment: I think it is because of the internal dns maybe? Still got the same message with "HostNotFound".